# replacing blocks in matlab

Tags: matlab, replace, block, simulink

i know this might be very simple, but i'm stuck for an hour at least..
I just cannot find out what the mistake is.( I read the docu)
Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

```
function y = in_out_modeling(~)

    model_name = 'modeladvisor_test';

    all_input_blocks = find_system('modeladvisor_test', 'FollowLinks', 'on', 'LookUnderMasks', 'all', 'BlockType', 'In');
    all_output_blocks = find_system('modeladvisor_test', 'FollowLinks', 'on', 'LookUnderMasks', 'all', 'BlockType', 'Out');

    for i=1:length(all_input_blocks)
        replace_block(model_name, all_input_blocks(i), 'From');
    end

    for i=1:length(all_output_blocks)
        replace_block(model_name, all_output_blocks(i), 'Goto');
    end
```

Comment: Can you please tell us what your problem exactly is? Do you get an error message? A [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating your problem would be helpful too.

Comment: That's the thing: no error, no warnings, nothing..
>> in_out_modeling
>> in_out_modeling(modeladvisor_test)
Warning: Output port 2 of 'modeladvisor_test/Subsystem' is not connected. 
Warning: Unconnected input line found on 'modeladvisor_test/Subsystem' (input port: 2) 
Warning: Unconnected input line found on 'modeladvisor_test/Subsystem' (input port: 1) 

>> in_out_modeling('modeladvisor_test')

Comment: That is how my command window looks like. The Simulink model doesn't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace_block replaces blocks by taking their BlockType as input. You are sending the path for those blocks as input which would not work. Try using,

```
replace_block(model_name, 'Inport', 'From')
```

The above will prompt you for each replacement. If you do not want to be prompted, use

```
replace_block(model_name, 'Inport', 'From', 'noprompt')
```

replace_block also will return the paths of the new blocks it inserted. You can use that list to verify whether you have all your blocks replaced.

If you would like to do your own search using find_system, then use 'Name' as an  argument to replace_block.

```
replace_block(model_name, 'Name', all_input_blocks(i), 'From', 'noprompt')
```

Comment: Thank you sir, that helped!

Answer (score 1):

There are no blocks with `BlockType` of `In` or `Out`.  Hence `all_input_blocks` is empty and you are not calling any of the `replace_block` code.  Similarly for the outputs.